# add button to specific post

Tags: php, debug

This code is designed to add a button to specific posts using the `get_post_meta` function. How do I alter the `get_post_meta` function to display this button on a specific post? I have already tried changing its `$post->ID` parameter to '1464', which is the post ID I want to use.

```
function custom_listify_single_job_listing_actions_after() {
    global $post;

    $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_custom_meta_key', true );

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" class="button">My Button</a>';
}
add_filter( 'listify_single_job_listing_actions_after', 'custom_listify_single_job_listing_actions_after' );
```

Comment: Cross posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37094609/1982136

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the hook you have used is correct; below is the updated code which you can use:

```
function custom_listify_single_job_listing_actions_after() {

    global $post;

    if( $post->ID == 1464 ) {

        $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_custom_meta_key', true );

        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" class="button">My Button</a>';
    }
}
add_filter( 'listify_single_job_listing_actions_after', 'custom_listify_single_job_listing_actions_after' );
```

Let me know how it goes.